# Swift: declare protocols inside classes

Tags: swift

In java I have:

```
public class Event {

        public enum State {
            PENDING,
            UPCOMING,
            ACTIVE,
            FINISHED,
            FAILURE
        }

        public interface Callback {
            void onUpdated();
            void onStateChanged(State state);
        }

        private State state;
        private Callback mCallback;
    }
```

How can I create something similar in Swift? Seems like I can not declare protocol inside class. But when I declare protocol outside I can not access State enum. Thanks.

I want to have something like

```
class Event {

    protocol Delegate {
        func onUpdated();
        func onStateChanged(state: State);
    }

    enum State {
        case PENDING
        case UPCOMING
        case ACTIVE
        case FINISHED
        case FAILURE
    }

    var delegate: Delegate?
}
```

Comment: You should include the Swift code you've written so far, even though it doesn't work.

Comment: I need to have class-scope enum state and class delegate, nothing more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access class scoped entities by using `className.[entity]` as in the following example:

```
protocol Callback {
  func onUpdated() -> Void
  func onStateChanged(state: MyClass.State) -> Void
}

class MyClass {
  enum State {
    case PENDING
    case UPCOMING
    case ACTIVE
    case FINISHED
    case FAILURE
  }

  private var state: State
  private var mCallback: Callback
}
```

Then you can just extend any other class with the `Callback` protocol like this:

```
class AnyOtherClass {
  ...
}

extension AnyOtherClass: Callback {
  func onUpdated() {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: What if I have many model objects that have Callbacks, so looks like I should name them differently and I can not keep them universal naming...., right?

Comment: Could you rephrase you question? I don't get it sorry

Comment: f.e. I have MyClass1 and MyClass2, so I should have Callback1 and Callback2, right? in Java I could have MyClass1.Callback and MyClass2.Callback

Comment: Well if the protocol is the same I don't see the problem to do so.
If the protocol differs, why having ProtocolClassA and ProtocolClassB is a problem? Note that I declared the Callback protocol outside of the MyClass defnition. This allow any other class to implement that protocol

Comment: @pvllnspk did you sort it out? Does it makes sense to use the same implementation of `Callback`?

Answer (score 1):

You can access `State` using `Event.State`

```
/* delegate protocol */
protocol MyDelegate : class {
    func onStateChanged(state: Event.State) -> ()
}

/* default implementation of onStateChanged */
extension MyDelegate {
    func onStateChanged(state: Event.State) {
        print("State changed to: \(state)")
    }
}

/* your events */ 
class Event {
    enum State {
        case Pending
        case Upcoming
        case Active
        case Finished
        case Failure
    }

    weak var delegate: MyDelegate?

    var state : State {
        didSet {
            // call delegate
            delegate?.onStateChanged(state)
        }
    }

    init(state: State) {
        self.state = state
    }
}
```

Example usage with some naive handlers:

```
class EventHandler: MyDelegate {
    var myEvent : Event

    init(event: Event) {
        myEvent = event
        myEvent.delegate = self
    }
}

class AnotherHandler: MyDelegate {
    var myEvent : Event

    init(event: Event) {
        myEvent = event
        myEvent.delegate = self
    }

    func onStateChanged(state: Event.State) {
        if state == .Active {
            print("Event is active")
        }
        else {
            print("Event is not active")
        }
    }
}

/* example usage */
let handler1 = EventHandler(event: Event(state: .Pending))
let handler2 = AnotherHandler(event: Event(state: .Pending))

handler1.myEvent.state = .Active 
    /* prints "State changed to: Active" (uses default delegate function) */

handler2.myEvent.state = .Active 
    /* prints "Event is active" (uses custom delegate function) */
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer, I've accepted the first answer that appeared.

Comment: @pvllnspk Happy to help. With regard to your questions in the comments to the other answer: note that two different classes (handlers above) can conform to `MyDelegate` and choose whether to implement a custom version of the blueprinted delegate function `onStateChanged(event:)` or whether to use the default implementation, as defined in the extension to `MyDelegate`.